# Cannot use local variable before it is declared

Tags: c#, function, parameters, scope

I am trying to create a function but I'm getting an error message.

```
public int[] genericSearch(int searchWidth, int startingRadius, int width, int height, Bitmap bitmap)
{
    //Generic function for finding the best path from a certain range
    if (startingRadius == -1)
        startingRadius = bitmap.Height() / 2;
```

> Cannot use local variable 'startingRadius' before it is declared.

The same problem occurs for the bitmap variable as well. Normally in c++ this type of declaration would work; however, I am unsure why it is not working here.

Comment: Note that Bitmap.Height is a property, so you'll need just `bitmap.Height`

Answer (score 82, accepted):

In visual studio. Sometimes when you declare a variable again (a second time). It will give this error. For example, this will sometimes throw the exception you mentioned:

```
 1.  int startingRadius = 0;
 2.  startingRadius = 5; <-- Exception thrown here.
 3.  
 4.  int startingRadius = 0;
```

Obviously this is incorrect anyway. So removing the second declaration (on line 4) will solve the problem.

Note: The exception you would ordinarily expect would be `A local variable named 'startingRadius' is already defined in this scope`. But for some reason, the exception you mentioned is shown sometimes.

Comment: Visual Studio should have changed this misleading error message. I like the `A local variable ... is already defined in this scope` error message.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a closing brace for your method but otherwise this code can compile on my machine...  (changed Height to a property as well)

```
public int[] genericSearch(int searchWidth, int startingRadius, int width, int height,Bitmap bitmap)
         {
         //Generic function for finding the best path from a certain range
             if (startingRadius == -1)
                 startingRadius = bitmap.Height / 2;
         }
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have a misplaced `}` or misspelled variable names.  I can't really tell without seeing the full code.

The error message is basically telling you that you have a local variable that you are trying to use which has not been declared.  Which suggests that the `if (startingRadius == 1)` code is actually inside a different method than the method you have declared.

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped to delete to local variable at all and create a new with different name...

```
Originally:

string butterfly;

butterfly = "butterfly with error"; <-- gives error
```

UPDTE:

Delete all the existing "butterfly"s and create new with new very similar name

```
string butterfly2;

butterfly2 = "butterfly without error" <-- worked for me perfectly.
```

*First tried:

1. clean and rebuild project - didn't help
2. restart whole program(IDE) - didn't help*

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate with a code example if possible?  It makes sense but for newer users variable scope could be confusing without elaborating.

Answer (score -1):

Change the variable name for example "butterfly" to "Butterfly" and declare it
under public partial class Form1 : Form
{
This is exactly where you have to declare it. It will then have scope for the entire class.
It worked for me.